# PHP code that chooses between multiple HTML banners

Tags: php

In the snippet below, I'm creating a banner for my website. If I change the variable in the html file, I want to call a different banner. It does work as is.

```
<?php $pencilbanner='hol'; include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/banner.html'); ?>
```

In my banner.html file, I'm holding all the banners. Each one with its own variable name.

```
<style type="text/css">
  <?php include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/dist/css/components/banner.css');?>
</style>

<div class="banner <?php if($pencilbanner == 'hol') echo 'holiday-banner' ; else echo 'standard-banner'?>">
  <?php if($pencilbanner == 'std'){ ?>
    <!-- Standard -->
    <h4>This is the standard banner</h4>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php if($pencilbanner == 'hol'){ ?>
    <!-- Holiday -->
    <h4>This is the holiday banner</h4>
  <?php } ?>

  <?php if($pencilbanner == 'lim'){ ?>
    <!-- Limited -->
    <h4>This is the limited time only banner</h4>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

The issue I'm having is in this line:

```
<div class="banner <?php if($pencilbanner == 'hol') echo 'holiday-banner' ; else echo 'standard-banner'?>">
```

At worst, this can end up being an endless chain of if/else statements, based on the banner I call. Ultimately, we intend on having multiple banners, and that can lead to `if else > else if > else if > else if > else if > else`, and I don't want to get there.

**What is the most direct approach to this without creating a long if/else statement?**

Comment: Why was my informative comment removed? It contained a relevant link to a source of pre-existing advice.

Comment: Great question. I didn't remove it. You can put it back if you want.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/272205/141885  same exact advice here.  If CodeReview ever closed duplicate questions, your question would be a good candidate.

Answer (score 2):

`$pencilbanner` can only contain one value (and you aren't changing it),  so using `if` over and over is most inappropriate and even using `elseif` would be an improvement.

Using a `switch` block is an appropriate technique since it only evaluates the variable once.  Personally, I try to avoid `switch` because I find all of the `breaks` to be ugly and verbose.

You could use a lookup array with keys like `hol`, etc. then associate the key with a subarray of the data you require.  If the `$pencilbanner` is not represented in the lookup array as a key, then coalesce to a fallback array of default values.

The most modern technique (available since PHP8), is `match`. It is compact and elegant.  Use its returned array to dynamically populate the desired HTML.

Suggested code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/rOg2o))

```
$bannerData = match($pencilbanner) {
    'std' => ['standard-banner', 'This is the standard banner'],
    'hol' => ['holiday-banner', 'This is the holiday banner'],
    'lim' => ['standard-banner', 'This is the limited time only banner'],
    default => [],
};

if ($bannerData) {
    vprintf('<div class="banner %s"><h4>%s</h4></div>', $bannerData);
}
```

Output with `$bannerData = 'hol';` *I added tabbing:

```
<div class="banner holiday-banner">
    <h4>This is the holiday banner</h4>
</div>
```

With this technique you will only need to add a new line of code in the `match` body -- never needing to touch the `vprintf()` code.

P.s. I'd probably name your file containing PHP as banner.php instead of banner.html.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response... holidays and all. In the area **"This is the standard banner"**, etc... can HTML markup be added there?

Comment: Of course, you can add HTML mark up within the `$bannerData` declaration -- there are not hard rules behind this.  Just try to not repeat yourself within these lookup elements.  Ideally, everything should only be written once -- this makes your code D.R.Y. (Don't Repeat Yourself).